# How to change label name from Course to Demos or something else in Tutor LMS in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, lms

Could any one please help to get to know how we can change terminology like Courses or Students to some other specific word related to LMS objective in tutor LMS plugin in Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what i got is, we need to do it manually on each and every page find and replace but its very lengthy and time consuming. Most of the pages changes are in Templates and views directory in tutor plugin. For side menu we can overwrite it by this

```
add_filter('tutor_dashboard/nav_items', 'add_some_links_dashboard');

function add_some_links_dashboard($links){
    $links['enrolled-courses'] = ["title" =>    __('Enrolled Demos', 'tutor'), "url" => "http://localhost/demos/index.php/dashboard/enrolled-courses/"];
    $links['my-courses'] = ["title" =>  __('All Demos', 'tutor'), "url" => "http://localhost/demos/index.php/dashboard/my-courses/"];
    return $links;
}
```